# Find and update items with multiple child elements

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have data as follows in MongoDB,

**ITEM DATA**

```
{
    id:1, 
    items: {3:'three', 4:'four'}

},
{
    id:2, 
    items: {}

},
{
    id:3, 
    items: {1:'one', 2:'two', 6:'six'}

},
{
    id:4, 
    items: {1:'one', 2:'two', 'three'}

},
{
    id:5, 
    items: {1:'one', 2:'two'}

},
{
    id:6,
    items: {1:'one'}
}
```

Also I have a map of items as follows locally,

**ITEM MAP DATA**

```
{
    1:'one',
    2:'two',
    3:'three',
    4:'four'
}
```

Lets say i need to insert `{5: 'five'}`, I need to insert `5` where there are two or many `items` from `ITEM MAP DATA`. the result should reflect something similar as follows,

**ITEM DATA RESULT**

```
{
    id:1, 
    items: {3:'three', 4:'four', 5'five'}

},
{
    id:2, 
    items: {}

},
{
    id:3, 
    items: {1:'one', 2:'two', 6:'six'}

},
{
    id:4, 
    items: {1:'one', 2:'two', 'three', 5:'five'}

},
{
    id:5, 
    items: {1:'one', 2:'two', 5:'five'}

},
{
    id:6,
    items: {1:'one'}
}
```

I am very new to this field and following was my attempt to achieve this,

```
var dataItemMap = {};

dataItemMap['1']='one';
dataItemMap['2']='two';
dataItemMap['3']='three';
dataItemMap['4']='four';


var setObj = {};


DbConnector.getMutProConnection(function(err,db) {

  setObj['5'] = 'five';

  db.collection('itemData').update({
    "$where": "return Object.keys(this.items).length > 1"
  }, {$set: setObj}, {multi: true});

});
```

I came up with the above code by reading through this post: [Mongodb Query based on number of fields in a record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281895/mongodb-query-based-on-number-of-fields-in-a-record) . But didn't seem to work and I dont know how to incorporate my second query.

I would be really grateful if you experts could provide me with code snippets, examples or references where I could achieve my requirement.

Thanks alot :)

Comment: mongodb does not support joins so trying to check if the item data is present in item_map would have to be done separately. If you don't have that condition of checking in the item_map then we should be able to form a query for that.

Comment: @anish I implemented kind of a static workaround for the requirement I have but its not the proper way. I also found out that joins are not possible in this and it would be great if we could form a query to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no joins in MongoDB, you would have to design your schema to avoid the lookup to "Item Map" or else you would have to check that in memory in your program. **Without** that condition, the query could be as below.

```
db.item_data.update({ "$where": "return Object.keys(this.items).length > 1" }, {$set : {"items.5" : "five"}}, false, true)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the post! i will check this and post back :)