# mongodb find a very strict document

Tags: mongodb, find

I want to return a very strict document that contain only a specific fields no more no less.

here is the situation:
document returned by `db.test.find()`

```
{"_id":ObjectId("562693f46fdf6dd2a0c97ad6"),"shape":"circle","color":"red","age": "20"}
{"_id":ObjectId("562694046fdf6dd2a0c97ad7"),"shape":"circle","color":"blue","age": "42"}
{"_id":ObjectId("562694306fdf6dd2a0c97ad8"),"shape":"circle","color":"green"}
{"_id":ObjectId("562694306fdf6dd2a0c97ad8"),"shape":"blabla","color":"blabla"}
```

how can i return the document that have only the fields: shape and color, and omit all other document that have more other fields on them. so the result should look like:

```
{"_id":ObjectId("562694306fdf6dd2a0c97ad8"),"shape":"circle","color":"green"}
{"_id":ObjectId("562694306fdf6dd2a0c97ad8"),"shape":"blabla","color":"blabla"}
```

edit:
all others fields are unknown, so using age:{$exists:false}} is not possible

Comment: How about db.test.find({},{shape:1,color:1}). The second block of the find() is projection which let's you specify what fields you would like to return. _id field is always returned unless you explicitly choose not to. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: @SriniKandula, no, this will return all the document with shape and color fields, what i need is return only the last two document

Comment: How about this? db.test.find( { shape: { $exists: true},  color: { $exists: true}, age: { $exists: false} } )

Comment: Well, this would assume that you know exhaustively all the other potential properties...

Comment: @dgiugg, that the major problem, all others properties are unknown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to check for the existence of both fields and constrain to results that have exactly 3 fields (shape, color, _id):

```
db.test.find({
    shape: { $exists: true },
    color: { $exists: true },
    $where: function() { return Object.keys(this).length === 3 }  
})
```

There are also alternatives to using `$where` noted by this answer: [Mongodb Query based on number of fields in a record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281895/mongodb-query-based-on-number-of-fields-in-a-record)

Comment: return Object.keys(this).length === 3 and not 2, because the id is included