# Exact match on the embedded document when field order is not known

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#exact-match-on-the-embedded-document) says:

> To specify an equality match on the whole embedded document, use the
>   query document `{ <field>: <value> }` where `<value>` is the
>   document to match. Equality matches on an embedded document require an
>   *exact* match of the specified `<value>`, including the field order.

Using the dot notation is not a fully satisfying solution, as it also matches docs embedding docs with more fields than than required. And I may not know which are the other possible fields, making it impossible to explicitly exclude undesirable fields.

Querying each possible combination of fields is also not desired, as I do not want to write (#fields)! queries.

How then can I find a doc that contains an embedded doc when I do not care about the order of the fields?

---

For example, assume a collection of documents following this schema, but the order of the fields of `inner` are not known or may vary, depending on how/when they were inserted:

```
{
_id: ObjectId()
inner: {
    some_field: some_value,
    some_other_field: some_other_value
    }
}
```

If I want to get all documents containing an `inner` object as `{some_field: some_value, some_other_field: some_other_value}`, I would want to

```
db.collection.find({inner:{some_field: some_value, some_other_field: some_other_value}})
```

but I will miss the docs with an `inner` object as `{some_other_field: some_other_value, some_field: some_value}`.

Using the dot notation like

```
db.collection.find({"inner.some_field": some_value, "inner.some_other_field": some_other_value})
```

will match all the documents I am interested in, but also include noise like

```
{
_id: ObjectId()
inner: {
    some_field: some_value,
    some_other_field: some_other_value,
    some_undesired_field: some_undesired_value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of framing this problem is that you want those two fields (in any order) *and no other fields in your result*.

Dot notation solves the first part of your problem and you can solve the second part by making sure `inner` only has 2 fields.

```
db.collection.find({
  "inner.some_field": some_value,
  "inner.some_other_field": some_other_value,
  $where: function() { return Object.keys(this.inner).length === 2 }  
})
```

I believe this is the easiest approach. The drawback to this approach is that `$where` can be slow for reasons detailed here: [Mongodb Query based on number of fields in a record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281895/mongodb-query-based-on-number-of-fields-in-a-record)

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the document that you want to find. It works for me but the order of fields is important too.

db.collection.find({"inner": {"some_field": some_value, "some_other_field": some_other_value }}).pretty();

I just read that field order is unknown. So you have to use $or to list the possibilities such as:

db.collection.find({$or:[{"inner": {"some_field": some_value, "some_other_field": some_other_value }}, {"inner": {"some_other_field": some_other_value, "some_field": some_value }}]}).pretty();

Comment: That's what I was thinking of. But assume my object contains N fields, I would have to write N! expressions for the `or` operator? This sounds like overkill for N>2. I hoped there would be a more usable solution.

Comment: That is right, it would not be very practical for more than two fields. I'm going to test other operators like $in to see how they behave when trying to match a whole document.